# ESP32-S3 with AWS-FreeRTOS. Can't create a proper JSON with asprintf()

Tags: aws-iot

I have a MAC MOnterey 12.6.3 and installed all necessary espressif toolchain.

I just installed [AWS-FreeRTOS](https://github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot) in a ESP32-S3 and ran the `mqtt/tls_mutual_auth` example. This example is to publish a `hello world` in the AWS-I0T core mqtt broker.

It is working. The problem is that I want to publish a JSON like this `{"certs_state": "2"}`. The code to do that is the following:

```
char *myString=NULL;
int x = 2;
asprintf(&myString, "{\"certs_state\": \"%d\"}", x);

// outgoingPublishPackets[ publishIndex ].pubInfo.pPayload = MQTT_EXAMPLE_MESSAGE;
outgoingPublishPackets[ publishIndex ].pubInfo.pPayload = myString;
```

The portion `outgoingPublishPackets[ publishIndex ].pubInfo.pPayload =` is where you pass the string you want to publish. I replaced the variable `MQTT_EXAMPLE_MESSAGE "Hello World!"` which is in the line 194 in the [original code](https://github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot/blob/release/202210.01-LTS/examples/mqtt/tls_mutual_auth/main/mqtt_demo_mutual_auth.c) by another variable `myString` to be used in the line 1361 in the same code.

My goal is to publish a JSON like this `{"certs_state":"2"}` but I am getting a JSON like this `{"certs_state":"2"` published in the AWS-IoT Core. The `}` is missing.

I am testing my code in another [C Online Compiler](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/), using the same coe I am using inside the FreeRTOS and I am getting the correct result:

```
// Online C compiler to run C program online
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *myString=NULL;
    int x = 2;
    asprintf(&myString, "{\"certs_state\": \"%d\"}", x);
    printf(myString);
    return 0;
}

//Output {"certs_state": "2"} as expected.
```

The conclusion is that the code is not wrong. Maybe there is something more causing the issue. Any idea what that could be?

UPDATE

---

I think I found portion of the issue, I guess. Maybe it was not working because of the quantity of characters.
If I remove the `"` it releases enough space to create the full string `{"certs_state": 3}`, without `"`.
[image]
code is :

```
char *myString=NULL;
int x = 3;
asprintf(&myString, "{\"certs_state\": %d}",x);
```

But it is still not a JSON.

In another test if I use `x = 3456` it only display until the `5`:
[image]
and the code is:

```
char *myString=NULL;
int x = 3456;
asprintf(&myString, "{\"certs_state\": %d}",x);
```

Doing another test with a small JSON:
[image]
The code is:

```
char *myString=NULL;
int x = 3;
asprintf(&myString, "{\"t\":\"%d\"}",x);
```

It seems that there is no enough memory allocated to that simple string. And besides that it seems that `{"t":"3"}` is not a JSON.

any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tested that code on the ESP32? That would tell you more than testing it im “C Online Compiler”.

Comment: Is there maybe a packet size limit somewhere which would be exceeded?

Comment: I added an update

Comment: Again, I am asking you to print out the value generated by asprintf() in your ESP32 program. I don’t want to know what AWS showed. I want to know what asprintf() generated immediately after you called it, from the ESP32, not an online simulator, not after you try to send it to AWS.